# Clone of an object inherits future changes that are made to first object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

Lets say you have this object:

```
mainObj = {
   foo1: 'bar1',
   foo2: 'bar2',
   foo3: 'bar3'
}
```

Now I want to make a close of this object by doing `cloneObj = mainOb`. Now we have two identical objects.

When I change the value of `mainObj.foo1 = 'lolcats'` *after* I made the clone then for some reason `cloneObj.foo1 = 'lolcats'`

I tested this in Chrome's console on a much more complex object. I know for certain that there's nothing in my script that would keep making the two objects sync up. I even made sure of this by creating random names for the cloneObj.

Is this behavior done on purpose or am I experiencing some sort of bug? Or am I just missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't clone the initial object when you just did `cloneObj = mainOb`, you are actually passing a reference to `mainOb` that can be accessed via the `cloneObj` variable name.  You therefore have two variable names referencing the SAME object.

Comment: Okay... Haha. Guess I was missing something fundamental here. :)

Answer (score 2):

when you assign/clone object such as `cloneObj = mainOb` you just create another reference to the same object. Both `mainOb` and `cloneOb` points to the same object thus, a change in one is reflected on another.